# React navigation header for tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator embedded in a stack navigator. I want to have the header title as the title of the currently active tab. How can I do it?

Here's what my stack looks like:

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home,
  Bookings,
  UserCenter,
  Wallet,
  Help
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  },
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false
});

const App = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs,
  HelpQuestion,
  Service,
  Category,
  BookNow,
  Favorites,
  BookingSummary,
  Referral,
  Search,
  Login,
  Signup
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions:({navigation}) => {
    // let title = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index])
    return {headerTintColor: '#EA0600'}
  }
})
```

Comment: you can do something like this
export default class ListTabs extends React.PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Bookings',
    tabBarLabel: 'Bookings',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Image
        source={require('../../../Assets/tabBarGuidesIcon.png')}
        style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
      />
    ),
  }

Comment: @HaiderAli and listtabs replaces the Bookings screen?